# Thymeleaf - template architecture

Tags: java, thymeleaf

What is the best way to build a template architecture?

Option 1:
java

```
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String doGet(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("include", new Include("main","main"));
        return "index";
    }
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

  ...
  header code
  ...
  
  <div th:replace="~{${include.path} :: ${include.name}}"></div>
  
  ...
  footer code
  ...
  
</body>
</html>
```

Option 2:
java

```
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String doGet(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("data", data);
        return "index";
    }
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="~{header :: header}"></div>

  ...
  main code
  ...

  <div th:replace="~{footer:: footer}"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using the first option, but I'm not sure if it's the right one.

Which is better: load the target fragment into a ready-made index template, or load elements (footer, header, ...) around the target fragment?

Comment: Your first answer looks to me as a weird way to get the functionality that thymeleaf layout dialect already offers (https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-spring-layouts). For the given options, personally i'd say the second is better as "fragments" seem better to me as reusable code blocks. putting you main body into a fragment seems off to me

Comment: For me, the second method looks strange, because if we want to modify the main template, it will have to be changed for each view. What is the best practice? How do companies do it?

Comment: I would definitely recommend [layout dialect](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html#thymeleaf-layout-dialect) for this over those two options.

Comment: In the same place, in paragraph 5, they offer my second option - [link](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html#thymeleaf-custom-layout)